# iMac says Storage is full but I only used 10GB out of 1TB of storage...?

Tags: imac, storage

[image][image]This is very weird. New iMac. 4 months old, brand new. 1 Terabyte of storage. The Mac keeps saying I am out of storage, but when you add up all of my word docs, downloads, applications, etc., it only totals about 10Gb. Then when I click on "manage storage" it gives me a breakdown of what my computer is using and at the bottom line it says "system: 990 GB" - Shouldn't the system be operating at about 8-9GB tops?!!? I have deleted all surplus items and literally the total of all downloads, documents, files, applications, etc. is only about 10GB but it says my storage is almost full!! Please help!

I put up a photo of the storage management screen before I deleted some more stuff.... This is nuts.

Comment: That screenshot says your *System* is using nearly a TB.  Did you buy this iMac brand new from Apple or other reputable retailer, or from another source?

Comment: This was purchased brand new from Apple. As I mentioned  in the post, the system says its using 990GB, but that's crazy. What could this be?

Comment: Could you please scan your computer with Disk Inventory X (http://www.derlien.com/) and attach a screenshot? It would be very helpful to know what files take up the most space.

Comment: Ok, I added a screenshot of the Disk Inventory X scan. See above. It shows that my "log file" is taking up 895GB...

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me once. I used [Daisy Disk](https://daisydiskapp.com/) to figure out where the disk usage was coming from.

---

In my case, there was a problem with the **coresymbolicationd** cache, which was growing indefinitely (eating up hundreds of gigabytes).

After deleting `/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.coresymbolicationd`, everything returned to normal.